# Template with comparator function with custom parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, types

I am working on a data structure and I want it to have comparison function, that can be passed to the constructor, the same way as stl data structures (set, queue, etc.) work. I also want a default function provided in the constructor.

The problem is, that the query to the structure is a function template, that takes custom type as a parameter. But I don't know how to provide the default comparison function if I don't know what type the query will be. Is there a way to do this?

This works if the Query is the same as the NodeType (Query is useless in this example):

```cpp
template<class NodeType, class Query = NodeType>
inline float eucDistance(const Query * p1, const NodeType * p2) {
    ...
}


template<class NodeType, typename Comp = decltype(eucDistance<NodeType>)>
class KDTree {

    Comp* distance;

public:

    KDTree(Comp comaprator = &eucDistance<NodeType>) : distance(comaprator) {

    }

    template<class Query = NodeType>
    NodeType * nearestNeighbor(const Query *query) {
        ...
        float tmp = distance(query, sth); 
        //I want something like distance<NodeType, Query>(query, sth); 
        ...
   }
}
```

But I would like to do something like this:

```cpp
class Point; //some type that the tree contains

KDTree<Point> tree;
Point p1;
Point *p = tree.nearestNeighbor(&p1); //this works with the given example
...
vec3 vec = ...; //some different type as a query
p = tree.nearestNeighbor<vec3>(vec); // <-- this is what I would like to do
```

Comment: If each call to query can have a different type as argument that affects the comparator called, then instead of passing the comparator to the class, shouldn't the comparator be passed to the function?

Comment: No, the comparator will be the same for different queries. It will be different only for different instances of the class. The comparator will call only `operator[]` on the query, so it can easily accept different types.

Comment: In the above example, since `KDTree<Point>` has `Point` as `NodeType` type the `nearestNeighbour(&p1)` works since the types match; this means that when the `NodeType` passed to the queried function is different from the one passed to the class' constructor, then it won't work `nearestNeighbour(vec)`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I want to know if it is a way how to make the comparator work with different types. Obviously it can't be passed to the constructor the way I do it now, that's what I haven't figured out...

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename Query, typename NodeType = Query>
inline float eucDistance(const Query * p1, const NodeType * p2) {
    ...
}

class KDTree {
public:
    template<typename Query = NodeType, typename Comparator>
    NodeType * nearestNeighbor(const Query *query, Comparator comp) {
        ...
        float tmp = comp(query, sth);
        ...
   }
}
```

This code takes in the comparator at the member function level due to which it can take on different type of nodes. Also the template type deduction will work; so instead of calling function like thus `comp<T>(a, b);` just `comp(a, b)` should work.

The main difference between your code and C++ standard library functions (algorithms) taking a comparator argument is that they don't enforce them to be pointers or rather C-style pointer to functions. Instead they use [functors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/356950/183120).

Take `std::for_each` which calls a functor for the elements passed; it takes a functor thus

```
template <typename InputIter, typename UnaryFunc>
UnaryFunc std::for_each(InputIter first, InputIter last, UnaryFunc func)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        func(*first);
    return func;
}
```

If you notice, there're no pointers. It calls `func` with the operator `()`; the beauty of this is that it works for both C-style function pointers and also C++ style functors i.e. a `struct` with an `operator()` defined. Also notice that the template type used for the functor is agnostic of what type the functor accepts.

Comment: I now this is a possibility, but it's really not practical... if you make the queries on multiple places in your code, you need to have the comparator available everywhere, which adds additional code and complexity...

Comment: Usually utility functions and standalone algorithms, like the Euclidean distance function, are in a common header which can be called/referred to from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should use polymorphic functor instead of plain function, for example

```
struct eucDistance
{
    float operator()(Point, Point) const;
    float operator()(vec3, Point) const;
    ...
};
```

BTW, you really should take a look at [Boost.Geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html) and it's [R-tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes.html) design.

Comment: This still makes me declare all acceptable types in advance, I'm looking for a generic solution if possible. Thanks for the link, I'll look at it.